# How do I port forward from a remote server through a jump box

Tags: ssh

I'm not sure if I'm using the right term of "port forwarding". What I want to do is connect to a local port that to connects to a remote server on a private network.

local --> jump-box --> server

On the server, a webserver is running on port 80
On local I would like to have my browser connect to localhost:8080 and reach the server's port 80.
The jump-box is a standard port 22 ssh server.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
ssh <user>@<server ip> -o 'ProxyCommand ssh <user>@<jump box> nc <server ip> 22 2>/dev/null' -f -L <local port>:localhost:<server port> -N
```

for example

```
ssh jsmith@web.local -o 'ProxyCommand ssh jsmith@gateway.example.com nc web.local 22 2>/dev/null' -f -L 8080:localhost:80 -N
```

Comment: Newer versions have the easier [parameter `-J`](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/command/#sec-SSH-command-line-options)